# Save form data in mobile app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, backbone.js

I create an app by backbone js that when is submitted, form data is stored in a txt file. it works properly in windows.
here is my code:

```
var pom = document.createElement('a');
pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(mytext));
pom.setAttribute('download', filename);
pom.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(pom);
pom.click();
document.body.removeChild(pom);
```

then I created an APK by Cordova. When I install the APK on my mobile and submit the form, the txt file don't save in my mobile.
What is the problem ?
is there any other way to save form data in my app on mobile?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the File plugin to save documents to your device.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file

Note the differences between OS's regarding where to store files.

Some example code below:

```
function writeToFile(fileName, data) {
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, function (directoryEntry) {
    directoryEntry.getFile(fileName, { create: true }, function (fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {
            fileWriter.onwriteend = function (e) {
                // for real-world usage, you might consider passing a success callback
                console.log('Write of file "' + fileName + '" completed.');
            };
            fileWriter.onerror = function (e) {
                // you could hook this up with our global error handler, or pass in an error callback
                console.log('Write failed: ' + e.toString());
            };
            var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/plain' });
            fileWriter.write(blob);
        }, errorHandler.bind(null, fileName));
    }, errorHandler.bind(null, fileName));
}, errorHandler.bind(null, fileName));
}
```

This creates a file then writes the variable called data to the file. and gives it a file name that I want to give it.